# Does `jsonParsed` always work for `getTokenAccountsByOwner`?

Tags: rpc, jsonrpc-api

The [docs](https://edge.docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettokenaccountsbyowner) for the `getTokenAccountsByOwner` RPC method say:

> If "jsonParsed" is requested but a parser cannot be found, the field falls back to "base64" encoding.

However since we're dealing with token accounts, I think the RPC node will always know how to parse these (at least based on the current version of the RPC code), so it will never return `base64` data unless I ask for it. The same goes for `getTokenAccountsByDelegate`.

Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Confirming that yes, it always works.  If not, please submit an issue!

Answer (score -1):

the answe is yes. Reviewing the docs, you can see it will return in this format:
Results
pubkey:  - the account Pubkey
account:  - a JSON object, with the following sub fields:
lamports: , number of lamports assigned to this account
owner:, Pubkey of the program this account has been assigned to
data: , Token state data associated with the account, either as encoded binary data or in JSON format {: }
executable: , boolean indicating if the account contains a program (and is strictly read-only)
rentEpoch: , the epoch at which this account will next owe rent

As u can see there is no b64 in there, ever

Comment: Fix grammar and capitalization please